# Create a deeply nested form using bootstrap for responsiveness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a scenario were forms are dynamically rendered. The form could be deeply nested by any number of levels using a ul list.

```
<ul>
    <li>LABEL + INPUT</li>
    <li>LABEL + INPUT</li>
    <li>
       <ul>
          <li>LABEL + INPUT</li>
          <li>LABEL + INPUT</li>
       </ul>
       .....
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using the bootstrap grid to align labels and inputs. If we specify a width of col-sm-2 for all labels, the deeper a nest level is the smaller the 12-grid width it has to work with. For instance, col-sm-2 at nest-level 3 is smaller than col-sm-2 at nest-level 1. This is because bootstrap bases it's width calculation on viewport width, not the width of the element's parent.

Here is a demo of what I am trying do: https://jsfiddle.net/s85g/jgr3uz6e/10/

As you can see, the deeper the level the smaller the label width. At some point the label will overflow. I need to find a way to stack the columns when there isn't enough room for the label. I want the label to be readable at any level, while at the same time maintaining a responsive layout.

I am trying to avoid specifying a static width for labels in css.

I read about element queries and some of the hacks available in JS + CSS, but I am hoping there is a simpler solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You should post an actual example of your layout. See [mcve].

Comment: @vanburen I have updated the post with a jsfiddle, thanks.

Comment: In every single "nest" could the total width of each section not be the same i.e. 12 grids? Does it necessarily have to be smaller each time you have a nested field?

Comment: @mohammedkhan I am not sure I understand what you are suggesting. Since the number of nesting levels is arbitrary, I do not know of a way to override bootstrap's width rendering at each level.